# change breadcrumb separators while Omega subtheme

Tags: 7, theming, breadcrumbs

How do you change breadcrumb separators when using Omega subtheme? I tried the usual breadcrumb hook, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you moved your breadcrumb to a delta block? If so, try `themename_delta_blocks_breadcrumb($variables)`.

Answer (score 2):

Lances answer was right, but just in case I'll put the code here.

```
function theme_delta_blocks_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $output = '';

  if (!empty($variables['breadcrumb'])) {  
    if ($variables['breadcrumb_current']) {
      $variables['breadcrumb'][] = l(drupal_get_title(), current_path(), array('html' => TRUE));
    }

    $output = '<div id="breadcrumb" class="clearfix"><ul class="breadcrumb">';
    $switch = array('odd' => 'even', 'even' => 'odd');
    $zebra = 'even';
    $last = count($variables['breadcrumb']) - 1;    

    foreach ($variables['breadcrumb'] as $key => $item) {
      $zebra = $switch[$zebra];
      $attributes['class'] = array('depth-' . ($key + 1), $zebra);

      if ($key == 0) {
        $attributes['class'][] = 'first';
      }

      if ($key == $last) {
        $attributes['class'][] = 'last';
      }

      $output .= '<li' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $item . '</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul></div>';
  }

  return $output;
}
```